# Calculating series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$S_n$=1+2+3......=n(n+1)/2

$P_n$=$\frac{S_2}{S_2-1}$.$\frac{S_3}{S_3-1}$........$\frac{S_n}{S_n-1}$

Then lim $P_n$ where n tends infinity

On solving $P_n$
I got

$\frac{3}{2}$.$\frac{6}{5}$$\frac{10}{9}$.....

So general term becomes

$\frac{x^2/2 +3x/2+1}{x^2/2+3x/2}$

How should I proceed further since the terms are getting multiplied and not added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that for $r\ge 2, \frac {S_r}{S_r -1}=\frac{r(r+1)}{(r+2)(r-1)}$ and take log on both sides to get:

$\begin{align}\log P_n= &\sum_{r=2}^n\log \frac{r(r+1)}{(r+2)(r-1)}\\&=\sum_{r=2}^n (\log r+\log (r+1)-\log (r+2)-\log(r-1))\\&=\sum_{r=2}^n (\log r-\log(r-1))+\sum_{r=2}^n(\log (r+1)-\log (r+2))\end {align}$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Ya got it as 3 thanks

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{S_r}{S_r-1}=\dfrac{\dfrac r{r-1}}{\dfrac{r+2}{r+1}}=\dfrac{Q_r}{Q_{r+2}}$$ where $Q_n=\dfrac n{n-1}$

$$P_m=\prod_{r=2}^m\dfrac{S_r}{S_r-1}=\dfrac{Q_2Q_3}{Q_{m+1}Q_{m+2}}$$

Finally set $m\to\infty$ and find $$\lim_{m\to\infty}Q_{m+1}=?$$